# Celtx unexpectedly quits

Tags: software, crash

I am using [Celtx](http://www.celtx.com) for script-writing/movie production. Just earlier today, I used it with no problems at all. Now, when I open it, it bounces 2-3 times, then quits. If I open a Celtx file, the file will open and load, then quit. I can't do anything with Celtx at all. Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that you are using the latest version of Celtx, I think that it's most likely that one of the Celtx preference files have become corrupted. You'll find them in two locations:

Preference file:

```
/Users/username/Library/Preferences/ca.greyfirst.celtx.plist
```

Preference folder:

```
/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Celtx
```

I'd do the following to troubleshoot:

1. Quit Celtx. Not a problem, since you can't open it anyway.
2. Move the above listed files/folders to your Desktop.
3. Try to launch Celtx. If things work, great. Celtx will recreate the preferences. You will need to reset any user preferences you made.
4. If things don't work, I'd Trash the application, redownload it, and reinstall.
5. After reinstalling, restart your computer before you try to open the app again, just in case anything's being cached

Oh, and best of luck with your script!

Comment: I deleted both the .plist file and the prefs folder. It still doesn't work. I'm pretty sure I've reinstalled it already, but I'll try again.

Comment: I reinstalled...same problem.

Comment: Whew...restarted and the application was fine. (I would've restarted earlier, but I had iDVD creating a DVD) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Done. Glad to help.